# Alice special phone number

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Bob asked for Alice's phone number. Alice gave him her phone number but told him, "Until you tell me what pattern is hidden in my number, I won't receive your call."

**Help Bob to find the pattern in**

> **854-917-6320**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The digits are in alphabetical order:
>
> - eight
> - five
> - four
> - nine
> - one
> - seven
> - six
> - three
> - two
> - zero

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please take the tour and remember to hide your answer with spoiler tags.